# Undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Below is my index.html.erb (I just want to show a list of Brands and associated Subbrands)

```
<h1>Brands</h1>

<% @brands.each do |brand| %>
<h2><%= brand.name %></h2>
<% end %>

<% @brands.subbrands.each do |subbrand| %>
<h2><%= subbrand.name %></h2>
<% end %>
```

The error I receive when viewing index.html is:

```
undefined method `subbrands' for #<Array:0x9e408b4>
```

Here is my brands_controller:

```
class BrandsController < ApplicationController

def index
  @brands = Brand.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @brands }
  end
 end

end
```

Here is my routes.rb

```
Arbitrary::Application.routes.draw do

resources :brands do
  resources :subbrands 
  end

resources :subbrands do
   resources :subsubbrands
  end
```

Here is my brand.rb model

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, :presence => true

    has_many :subbrands
    has_many :subsubbrands, :through => :subrands
end
```

...and my subbrand.rb model

```
class Subbrand < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, :presence => true

    belongs_to :brand
    has_many :subsubbrands
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're saying this:

```
@brands = Brand.all
```

That means that `@brands` is now an Array because [`all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-all):

> A convenience wrapper for `find(:all, *args)`.

And [`find(:all)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find):

> Find all - This will return all the records matched by the options used. If no records are found, an empty array is returned. Use `Model.find(:all, *args)` or its shortcut `Model.all(*args)`.

Then you have this:

```
<% @brands.subbrands.each do |subbrand| %>
```

And that produces this error:

```
undefined method `subbrands' for #<Array:0x9e408b4>
```

Because `@brands` is an Array and Arrays don't know what `subbrands` means. Something like this might work better:

```
<% @brands.each do |brand| %>
    <% brand.subbrands.each do |subbrand| %>
        <h2><%= subbrand.name %></h2>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But you probably want to do something with the `brand` too.

Comment: Thank you for this. When I modified the index.html to include your suggestion I received another error: undefined method `each' for #<Brand id: 1, name: "brand1", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Comment: @Abram: Sorry, I left out the "subbrands" between `brand` and `each`, please see my update.