# Nested Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to display Brand and Subbrand together on a view page. I am getting an error when I try to declare:

```
class BrandsController < ApplicationController

def index
  @brands = Brand.all
  @subbrands = @brands.subbrands #error is coming from this line
```

Error:

```
undefined method `subbrands' for #<Array:0x9af1898>
```

I can't seem to get this working, for the life of me!

I originally posted about my problem in this post:
[Undefined method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964351/simple-problem-simple-solution)

I have tried to put the logic into the controller as above to see if that helps, but I am still getting the error. The details of the models and routing can be found in my original post.

Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple problem, Simple solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964351/simple-problem-simple-solution)

Comment: This is a duplicate and it was answered over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964351/simple-problem-simple-solution/6964472#6964472

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@brands` is an Array, not a single ActiveRecord object, so you can't call the `subbrands` association directly on it. Since you're calling `Brand.all`, and I assume all `Subbrand` items are associated with a `Brand`, you might as well just query all of the `Subbrand` objects separately:

```
@brands = Brand.all
@subbrands = Subbrand.all
```

However, if you were trying to only get a subset of the brands, you could do this. (The second line queries all the `subbrands` that have a `brand_id` included in `@brands`).

```
@brands = Brand.where(...)
@subbrands = Subbrand.where(:brand_id => @brands.collect(&:id))
```

Comment: From the rails guide: "For example, if you have an instance variable @post containing a post, you can retrieve all the comments belonging to that post as the array @post.comments." Why doesn't this work in my example?

Comment: In the rails guide, `@post` is a **single** post. In your case, `@brands` is an `Array` of `Brand` objects. You could call `@brands.first.subbrands`, but you can't call `subbrands` directly on `@brands`.